# Entity framework query to get array of role names for user

Tags: arrays, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have been trying to right a single query that can retrieve an array of the current users role names. I have gotten really close sadly my code doesn't return an array. I am fairly new to the entity framework and very confused on joins and inner queries within this language. If I was working in standard sql I would right a sub query to return all roles names where from roles where roleid is in user.roles.

Existing Code:

```
var user = from obj in db.Users
                       join obj2 in db.Roles on obj.Id equals obj2.Id
                       where obj.UserName == name select new {
                FirstName =obj.FirstName,
                LastName =obj.LastName,
                Email =obj.Email,
                JoinDate =obj.JoinDate,
                ProfilePic =obj.ProfileSettings.ProfilePicture,
                Roles = ""

            };
```

I don't want to use the current claims because I want to ensure that when getUser is called the most accurate roles are returned not the ones stored inside the access_token.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is doing a [`group join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx) like this

```
var user = from obj in db.Users
           join obj2 in db.Roles on obj.Id equals obj2.Id into roles
           where obj.UserName == name 
           select new {
            FirstName =obj.FirstName,
            LastName =obj.LastName,
            Email =obj.Email,
            JoinDate =obj.JoinDate,
            ProfilePic =obj.ProfileSettings.ProfilePicture,
            Roles = roles.Select(e=>e.Name)
          };
```

### Update

If you have `Roles` navigation property from `User` entity then you could do this:

```
var user = db.Users.Where(e=>e.UserName == name)
                   .Select(obj=>new {FirstName =obj.FirstName,
                                     LastName =obj.LastName,
                                     Email =obj.Email,
                                     JoinDate =obj.JoinDate,
                                     ProfilePic =obj.ProfileSettings.ProfilePicture,
                                     Roles = obj.Roles.Select(e=>e.Name)
                                    });
```

Comment: This is fine but instead of an array of just roles I want an array of the rolenames

Comment: If your tables are related and you have represented the relationship using navigation properties, then your query could be even easier. Do you have a nav property to roles in your `User` entity?

Comment: Firstly the .ToArray throws exceptions so I just removed it. Secondly I am not returning for roles the roles object is blank. Is there something wrong with the join on

Comment: This is the asp.net identity code first using identity user this is the default database that web api generates for users.

Comment: I then added some custom properties but aside from that it's the default database.

Comment: This is all fine and stuff aside from obj.Roles only contains the RoleId and the UserId. I just need to go a step further once you have obj.Roles I need to find the actual role objects that user contains by using the RoleId's from obj.Roles

Comment: You get that because Roles nav. Property represents a junction table. You should have a collection navigation property in Roles to go to the real Role table

Comment: Take a look if you can do this `obj.Roles.Select(e=>e.Role.Name)`

Answer (score 0):

I used what I understand about actual SQL and that is I would do a sub query to get this data. This works as I wanted.

Code:

```
var user = from obj in db.Users

                       where obj.UserName == name
                       select new
                       {
                           ID1 = obj.Id,
                           FirstName = obj.FirstName,
                           LastName = obj.LastName,
                           Email = obj.Email,
                           JoinDate = obj.JoinDate,
                           ProfilePic = obj.ProfileSettings.ProfilePicture,
                           Roles = (from info in obj.Roles
                                    from allData in db.Roles
                                    where allData.Id == info.RoleId
                                    select allData.Name).ToList()
                       };
```